# Finding the limit of a sum

Tags: calculus

I'm just blacked-out. I'm not sure how I should start.

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k \sin k}{n^3}} $$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\sin k\right|
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|k\sin k| \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{aligned}$$
so
$$\frac{1}{n^3}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\sin k\right| \leq \frac{n+1}{2n^2}$$
As the RHS converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, so does the LHS.

Comment: I assume you used the triangle inequality. But, how did you get from $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to $ \frac{n+1}{2n^2} $?

Comment: @Shalom.I Yes, the first line uses the triangle inequality. $\displaystyle \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ divided by $n^3$ is $\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{2n^2}$.

Comment: Oops. Thank you. One more question please, I assume you used the fact that $ 0 \leq |sink| \leq 1 $ in the second inequality?

Comment: @Shalom.I Yes, that's correct.

Comment: My comment is of no help. Just for curiosity, may be you could be interested by the fact that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\sin(k)=\frac{1}{4} \csc ^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) ((n+1) \sin (n)-n \sin (n+1))$$